# How can I install a nodejs project on a machine with no internet?

Tags: node.js, npm, offline, portability

I have been developing my nodejs project on my laptop.  I have installed all the dependencies of my project locally. Now I want to transfer my project into an offline machine.

The offline machine has nodejs environment pre-installed. I tried copying  the project to that machine but it didn't work ! **Modules I have installed are not working**

Example: I have gulp module installed in my project. when I run the gulp command it is not recognized.

Any help please?

Comment: If you just copy everything, executables won't be in your PATH. You can run them manually though: `node ./node_modules/.bin/gulp` or use npm scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but I am new to nodejs . what do you mean by npm scripts

Answer (score 1):

On the machine connected to the internet see if there is an environment variable called :

```
NODE_PATH
```

linux / OSX / Windows all have the notion of env variables.  If NODE_PATH is defined, it typically has a value like

```
echo $NODE_PATH

/home/stens/node-v5.0.0/lib/node_modules
```

All of node including npm and all globally installed modules live hanging off from parent directory :

```
/home/stens/node-v5.0.0  #  parent directory
```

On that same internet connected machine if you install `globally` all npm modules you will later be using offline then tarball or zip the entire parent directory like above into a single file which you then copy over to the offline machine then expand and define is own env var NODE_PATH and altered PATH it will work.  Here is how you globally install a npm module on your internet connected box

```
npm install xxxx -g
```

where xxxx is the module name

Additionally you will need to jack up the env var PATH on your offline machine so it can find location of executables like npm and node.  The following environment variable settings work to put the entire node infrastructure to hang off from directory ${HOME}/node-v5.0.0 on the offline machine

```
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v5.0.0  # <-- starting point dir use whatever

export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}  # <-- path to executables
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules
```

Beautiful thing about globally installing your npm modules is they are then available for use in any project without having to install them local to any node project

PS - what OS are you on ?

Here are the contents of my NODE_PARENT dir

```
cd ${NODE_PARENT}

~/node-v5.0.0

ls -la  ~/node-v5.0.0

drwxrwxr-x  7 stens stens 4096 Nov  2 15:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 80 stens stens 4096 Nov  3 11:28 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 stens stens 4096 Nov  2 15:46 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 stens stens 4096 Nov  2 15:45 etc
drwxrwxr-x  3 stens stens 4096 Nov  2 15:37 include
drwxrwxr-x  3 stens stens 4096 Nov  2 15:37 lib
drwxrwxr-x  5 stens stens 4096 Nov  2 15:37 share
```

hanging below its lib dir is

```
~/node-v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/   # <-- this dir contains all npm modules
```

Comment: Thanks Scott  for the answer . NODE_PATH is giving these values */usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript*

Comment: Btw I am using linux OS

Comment: Please tell us if you need more info - have fun